# Regexpr with a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to get the result from this regular expression; the regular expression is a string in a variable:

```
const dataFileUrlRegExpr = new RegExp(            
    "\\/home-affairs\\/document\\/download\\/([\\\\w-]{1,})_en?filename=visa_statistics_for_consulates_20[0-9]{2}.xlsx"
);
href = '/home-affairs/document/download/75ecba81-12db-42b0-a628-795d3292c680_en?filename=visa_statistics_for_consulates_2020.xlsx'

xlslHrefRegExpResult = dataFileUrlRegExpr.exec(xlslHref);
```

but the xlslHrefRegExpResult variable is null.

If I use:

```
const dataFileUrlRegExpr = new RegExp(
    /\/home-affairs\/document\/download\/([\w-]{1,})_en\?filename=visa_statistics_for_consulates_20[0-9]{2}.xlsx/g
);
```

without the string variable containing the expression, the result is achieved.
Where is the error using a string to build the regexp?

Comment: Why are you using a string instead of a RegExp literal? You should only use `new RegExp()` when you're creating the regexp dynamically.

Comment: `[\\\\w-]` should be `[\\w-]`

Comment: If you just printed the two regular expressions in the console you would have seen the difference.

Comment: `_en?` should be `_en\\?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code should be:

```js
const dataFileUrlRegExpr = new RegExp(            
    "\\/home-affairs\\/document\\/download\\/([\\w-]{1,})_en\\?filename=visa_statistics_for_consulates_20[0-9]{2}.xlsx", 'g'
);
href = '/home-affairs/document/download/75ecba81-12db-42b0-a628-795d3292c680_en?filename=visa_statistics_for_consulates_2020.xlsx'

xlslHrefRegExpResult = dataFileUrlRegExpr.exec(href);
console.log(xlslHrefRegExpResult)
```

You had too many backslashes in `[\\\\w-]`, and you were missing the backslashes before `?`./

Answer (score 0):

- Don't escape `/` at all, because it's nothing special inside a non-literal regex.
- Do escape the backslash in `\w`, but only once.
- Do escape the `?` and the backslash itself.
- Do escape the `.` and the backslash itself.

```
dataFileUrlRegExpr = new RegExp(            
    "/home-affairs/document/download/([\\w-]{1,})_en\\?filename=visa_statistics_for_consulates_20[0-9]{2}\\.xlsx"
);
```

In short: write your regexp as normal, but double every backslash inside it so that it doesn't get interpreted as an escape character inside the string.